# how to combine mysql query in CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I need to combine those two array into a single array.

1st query result

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [p_type] => Bank [tsales] => 131000 [tdues] => 55000 [tpaid] => 75000 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [p_type] => Cash [tsales] => 104000 [tdues] => 50000 [tpaid] => 54000 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [p_type] => bKash [tsales] => 25000 [tdues] => 10000 [tpaid] => 5000 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [p_type] => Pause [tsales] => 4000 [tdues] => 1000 [tpaid] => 2000 ) )
```

2nd query result

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [dpayment] => 1000 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [dpayment] => 5000 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [dpayment] => 1000 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [dpayment] => 5000 ) )
```

Comment: Maybe use codeigniter join database  http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

Answer (score 0):

try to use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php). That should be very easy.

Answer (score 0):

Your query result shows that you using $query->result() to get the value,

Instead of using result(), use $query->row_array();

then you get single dimensional array for both queries

then use `array_merge()` that would be easy